# How to use an existing flask-sqlalchemy class as a definition in flask-swagger

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, swagger, flask-sqlalchemy, flasgger

I have followed the [README](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger) - specifically, [this example](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger#using-docstrings-as-specification) - to create an OpenAPI definition and Swagger UI for my simple Flask-with-sqlalchemy app:

```py
# main.py
#...

@app.route("/player", methods=["POST"])
def create_player():
    """Create a Player
    ---
    requestBody:
      description: Payload describing the player
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
                example: Jim Bloggs
            required:
              - name
    responses:
      201:
        description: Payload containing Player Id
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: number
          required:
            - id
    tags:
      - player
    """
    player = Player(name=data[request.json["name"]])
    db.session.add(player)
    db.session.commit()
    return {"id": player.id}, 201


@app.route("/player/<player_id>")
def get_player(player_id: str):
    """Get a Player
    ---
    parameters:
      - name: player_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: integer
          minimum: 1
        description: The Player Id
    responses:
      200:
        description: Payload describing player
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                id:
                  type: number
                  required: true
                name:
                  type: string
                  required: true
      404:
        description: Player not found
        content:
            application/json: {}
    tags:
      - player
    """
    player_from_db = db.session.get(Player, int(player_id))
    if not player_from_db:
        return "Not Found", 404

    return _jsonify_and_remove_sqlalchemy_property(player_from_db)


# Note to StackOverflow readers - if you know a better way to do this, let me know!
def _jsonify_and_remove_sqlalchemy_property(o):
    return {k: v for (k, v) in o.__dict__.items() if k != "_sa_instance_state"}
#...

# models.py
# where `db` is an instance of `SQLAlchemy()`

class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

This *works*, but the definition of a `Player` is manually copied in three locations. If I added more API paths that used the same object, I'd have to copy it again - and if the definition changed, I'd have to update it manually everywhere. Not great.

I can imagine a few decreasingly-satisfying solutions to this issue, none of which I've been able to figure out how to implement:

## Ideal solution - use class name directly in docstrings

Ideally, I'd like to be able to directly use the SQLAlchemy class' definition *in* the Swagger definitions - something like this (pseudo-syntax):

```py
#...
@app.route("/player", methods=["POST"])
def create_player():
    """Create a Player
    ---
    requestBody:
      description: Payload describing the player
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            derivedFrom: Player.class
...
"""
#...

@app.route("/player/<player_id>")
def get_player(player_id: str):
    """Get a Player
    ---
    parameters:
      - name: player_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: integer
          minimum: 1
        description: The Player Id
    responses:
      200:
        description: Payload describing player
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              derivedFrom: Player.class
...
"""
#...
```

In this hypothetical perfect situation, Flask would figure out that the `derivedFrom: Player.class` in the `requestBody` of `create_player` would *not* contain the `id` which is the PrimaryKey, but that the `derivedFrom: Player.class` in the `responses` of `get_player` *would*.

This is *probably* not possible in the vaguely-magical way I've described here, since Swagger *itself* probably needs to be informed of the classes to use when hydrating the specs - but I figured I'd describe it as the ideal approach in case there is a possibility that is somewhat closer to this than anything else I describe.

## Less-good-but-still-good solution - specify external definitions from a class

[OpenAPI has the notion of Components](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/), which are externalized fragments of various types (including schemas) that can be referenced in a spec. Something like this would be great:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)
# This next line is hypothetical
swagger.addSchemaFromClass(Player.class)

#...

@app.route("/player", methods=["POST"])
def create_player():
    """Create a Player
    ---
    requestBody:
      description: Payload describing the player
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Player"
...
"""

#...
```

Again, in an ideal world Swagger would be smart enough to know that a `POST` method that takes an object in the body should be lacking the `id`, whereas a `GET` method that returns it should have the `id` - but it's not the end of the world if that's not possible, the returning-cases should be far more numerous than the creation cases.

I did find `Swagger.definition`, which seems to be an annotation that can be used to do [*something* like this](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/blob/3c16b776f4848813209f2704b18cba81762ac030/examples/example_app.py#L249), but it's not ideal - it appears to still require docstrings to define the schema, rather than reading them from the class directly, at which point this becomes basically equivalent to the next option.

From [here](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/issues/296) it appears that direct class-based definitions can be achieved using another library named Marshmellow, which I'll explore if there are no better options using just the libraries I have (`Flask-SQLAlchemy` & `flasgger` (though I suspect it still won't do the intelligent "with/without `id`s" behaviour that I've described.

## Still acceptable solution - specify external definition directly

If there's a way of directly adding a `component` to swagger, I'm sure I could write a function to convert from a SQLAlchemy class to a definition, and do something like:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)
# This next line is hypothetical
swagger.addSchema(convertFromSqlAlchemyClassToSchema(Player.class))
# And, hey, if I'm going manual, I may as well also directly implement the with/without id logic I've referred to
swagger.addSchema(convertFromSqlAlchemyClassToSchemaWithoutPrimaryKey(Player.class))

#...

@app.route("/player", methods=["POST"])
def create_player():
    """Create a Player
    ---
    requestBody:
      description: Payload describing the player
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Player_WithoutPrimaryKey"
...
"""

#...
```

Failing all the previous solutions - is this possible? I see from [here](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/blob/master/examples/swagger_config_3_with_components_schemas.py#L12) that it is possible to specify `components` directly at init-time of the Swagger object - but then it looks like I'd have to specify my *whole* Swagger config directly, rather than using the docstring-based approach I'm already using, and I'd be loath to give up the colocation of the definition with the methods.

Comment: I'm not really sure of the meaning of this example: https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger#extracting-definitions - as these definitions are not actually referenced anywhere. If this means that "_if you put the key `id` in your definition of a schema, then that schema becomes a `definition` that you can reference in other APIs_", then this would be another less-than-ideal-but-still-acceptable solution, since it would still mean writing one definition in code (SQLAlchemy class) and one (but only one!) definition in docstring-spec.